# What's a clinical or all encompassing term for whether a person is alive or dead?

Tags: terminology

Male/Female comes under the category 'Gender'

What category does Living/Deceased come under?

I'm writing a webservice that clients will use, and data will come back like this:

```
person.Name = "Jeff"
person.Gender = GenderEnum.Male
person.Alive = AliveEnum.Alive or AliveEnum.Deceased
```

I need to use a clinical and non-offensive word instead of 'Alive' that is professional and makes sense, but I can't think of anything.

Also, `person.Alive = AliveEnum.Deceased` is a weird way to phrase it because Alive means what it means.

Comment: Must it be an `enum` value? Why not just `person.Alive = TRUE/FALSE`?

Comment: There's also UNKNOWN for when the data hasn't been supplied

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming of variables in code, which is specifically off-topic.

Comment: You should move this to EL&U. They'll love this question.

Comment: I think your `person.Alive = AliveEnum.Deceased` is confusing you. `person.Alive` will (generally) be `true` or `false`, and as those are perfectly good to describe whether a person is alive or not, `person.Alive` is entirely reasonable. The property `person.Alive` is different from the value `AliveEnum.Alive`: you can use `Alive` in more than one context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on computer programming, so please be merciful! :)

[***Living***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/living?showCookiePolicy=true) (noun) the state of being alive.

> *Living, alive*, the latter usually a predicate adjective, are the
>   simple, basic terms for organisms having life or existence, living
>   figuratively connoting continued existence or activity

This I feel expresses a neutrality which living/dead might be perceived as being insensitive or too direct. To the question "Is this person living?" I could reply: "yes/no/I don't know" So what about **Living y/n/?**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid an `IsAlive`-style category name, you could consider [vitality](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vitality?q=vitality):

> the power giving continuance of life, present in all living things: *the vitality of seeds*

So your data could look like:

```
person.Vitality = VitalityEnum.Alive or VitalityEnum.Deceased
```

Comment: There's even a Terry Pratchett novel where the undead complain about "vitalism".  (Discrimination by the living against those who aren't.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a boolean instead of an enum because there are only ever going to be two states. In that case, it could be called IsAlive, or IsDead. I wouldn't worry about this terminology. At a big bank I did some work for they didn't flinch from referring (in code) to a person's state in these terms, because it was never exposed to the client so there was never any chance of causing offence.

Alternatively, you could have a DateTime and call it DateOfDeath. If it's null the person is still alive. This is what some systems did.

Comment: Originally I was going to use a boolean, but there is the a third state - unknown - which is caused by having no data provided (missing data). There is potentially a 4th state of unknown where the data has been supplied, but states outright unknown. A subtle difference. I don't have to cater for the latter possibility, just the first three states. I think I might get away with using a nullable boolean but I was hoping for a nice enum term as in the future there's a small possibility of a state such as 'presumed dead'.

Comment: Interesting requirements. Depends on how likely a presumed dead state really is, I suppose. How about a 'StateEnum'? Unspecified/Unknown/Alive/Dead/PresumedDead? What about SchrödingerStateEnum? :) BiologicalState? Vitality?

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be to call your enum `Kleene` and allow it to be used for any true/false/unknown situation rather than just being alive.  Kleene logic extends Boolean logic with an "unknown/maybe" value.

```
person.Living = Kleene.True
person.Married = Kleene.False
person.LikesCilantro = Kleene.Unknown
```

If the language you are using allows for extending enums, you could even add appropriate logic operators.

```
Kleene.True.and(Kleene.Unknown) => Kleene.Unknown
```

Comment: What has the word "kleene" got to do with English language, I ask myself. This is computer science.

Comment: Kleene's K3 Logic is a form of three state logic compared to 2 state Boolean logic. As such "Kleene" is one of the most reasonable names to give to a 3 state logic data type.  "Ternary" is a bit vague, and "Łukasiewicz" is a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

Three states: **Live, Dead , Unknown**

I don't really understand why there should be a problem. I don't regard any of those words as offensive: merely statements of fact.

[If you're worried about whether being described as *Live* is offensive, you could be in a lot more trouble with *Gender* when you come to transsexuals, and others.]

Answer (score 0):

How about LifeStatus
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life

you can use kleene logic like so

LifeStatus = kleene.true;